# Process builder creating case twice

Tags: process-builder

I have a Process Builder on the Opportunity that creates a case 0 days from a certain date if the opportunity is a certain type, has a certain stage, and that date field has changed. We are also using a checkbox that gets updated in the same node to designate that the case has already been created. One of the entry criteria is that this checkbox is false. Yet, during testing, we're finding that 2 cases are being created. The checkbox is also checked, so we know that gets updated, yet it's not preventing duplicates.

The recursion checkbox is false, and since this is a time-based PB, the "Do you want to execute the actions only when specified changes are made to the record?" option is true. Everything I've found online so far says to set these options accordingly and to use a checkbox, and we're doing them, yet we're still getting duplicates. I checked the debug log and it doesn't look like the PB is running twice, which is the most confusing part. No, there aren't any other PBs on the Opportunity that are creating cases, and besides, the wording in the description is identical.

Comment: Try setting debug logs for the process automation user tracing flows. This should let you see what is specifically occurring

Comment: @GabrielM I looked at my own debug logs, is there a user that's used for automated processes like time-based flows that I would need to track in order to see what happened?

Comment: I would look for triggers or legacy workflows on Opportunity and also PB, trigger o legacy workflow in Case that may duplicate a new Case based on some criteria